# DropDownList how select default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have many DropDownLists on page

```
class BigViewModel
{
    public List<SmallViewModel> SmallVM {get;set;}
    public List<SelectListItem> Items {get;set;}
    //some other properties
}
class SmallViewModel
{
    public string ItemId {get;set;}
    //some other properties
}

<table>
    @for( var i = 0;i<Model.SmallVM.Count();i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropdownListFor(m=> m.SmallVM.ItemId, Model.Items)
            </td>        
        </tr>       
    }
//display other properties
</table>
```

in controller

```
bigViewModel.Items = List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{Value = "1", Text = "aaa"},
    new SelectListItem{Value = "2", Text = "bbb"},
    new SelectListItem{Value = "3", Text = "ccc"},
}
bigViewModel.SmallVM = new List<SmallViewModel>
{
    new SmallViewModel{ItemId = 3},
    new SmallViewModel{ItemId = 2},
}
```

In controller I set diffrent `ItemId` for every SmallVM and each DropDownList uses the same `Items` collection. I want to set default Value from SmallViewModel for each DropDownList. For example in this case there are two DropDownLists first should display default text "ccc" and second "bbb".

Should I put diffrent `List<SelectedListItem>` for every SmallViewModel and set them Selected property or there is other way?

Comment: You've either redacted too much from your code or otherwise haven't posted enough to be of use to answering this question. The only `Items` property that exists is a `List<SelectListItem>`, which should be the *second* parameter you pass to `Html.DropDownListFor`. Instead, you're using `Model.Members`, which isn't even defined here. Also, the individual items within `Items` are of type `SelectListItem`, which does not have an `ItemId` property.

Comment: Yes, of course its `Model.Items`

Comment: That doesn't really add anything. Post the actual model definition for your view and the `BigViewModel` and `SmallViewModel` classes (or at least *every* property on those that that's involved in the any of this, i.e. `Members`).

Comment: Oh, I see. You update the code in the question as well. `Model.Items` in place of `Model.Members`. That solves one problem, but the select list can't be both the thing you use to generate the dropdown *and* the property you post back to, and even then, the items still don't have an `ItemId` property, so I'm not even sure how you're getting this to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has been reported as a bug on CodePlex but not yet fixed. Using `DropDownListFor()` in a `for` loop does not bind correctly and the first option is always selected despite the value of the property. In order for `DropDownListFor()` to work correctly when using a collection, you need to use an `EditorTemplate` for the model.

In `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SmallViewModel.cshtml`

```
@model SmallViewModel
@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.ItemId, (SelectList)ViewData["Items"])
```

Then in the main view

```
@model BigViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  // Pass the select list to the EditorTemplate as addtionalViewData
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SmallVM, new { Items = Model.Items })
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

You should now have 2 `<select>` controls displaying "ccc" and "bbb" respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code updates, I *think* you just need to modify your view code to:

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m=> m.SmallVM[i].ItemId, Model.Items)
```

However, I have distinct feeling that this is very much an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and although this change will make everything wire up on post, you're still not going to be getting what you actually need for the true problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry, i edited again and there is like you post. I think I should modify my ViewModel and pass collection of SelectedListitem to each SmallViewModel.

Comment: You don't need multiple copies of your select list items.