# How to set default values on an array of controls using DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a view model that contains an array of objects.  Each of these objects has a pair of values that come from a drop down. Here is a cut down example:

```
public class MarketAllocation{
        public int MarketId;
        [SelectListProvider(typeof(ProvidersIdSelectListProvider))]
        public int Provider1Id { get; set; }
        [SelectListProvider(typeof(ProvidersIdSelectListProvider))]
        public int Provider2Id { get; set; }
}

public class EditViewModel{
    public List<MarketAllocation> MarketAlloctions;
    [SelectListProvider(typeof(ProvidersIdSelectListProvider))]
    public int Provider1Id;  // this is for testing purposes
}
```

There are a number of markets and each one has either one or two providers set.  In the view I'm using a custom helper to get the SelectListProvider attribute, using that to get a select list and then passing the list along with the expression through to the standard DropDownListFor helper.  So in the razor template I have:

```
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MarketAllocations.Count(); i++)
        {
                    @Html.MyDropDownListFor(m => m.MarketAllocations[i].Provider1Id)
                    @Html.MyDropDownListFor(m => m.MarketAllocations[i].Provider2Id)
        }
        @Html.MyDropDownListFor(m => m.Provider1Id)
```

And the helper is like this:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString MyDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) where TModel : class
    {
        /// code to get the select list removed for brevity
        return html.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList);
    }
```

The Dropdowns from the MarketAllocations both render but both default to the first item in the list.  The Provider1Id from the EditViewModel defaults to the correct value in the dropdown.  I have added TextBoxFors to render the ProviderId values from the MarketAllocations and can see that they are set correctly.  This leads me to think that the issue is the array as the expression that is passed to DropDownListFor is like this:

```
m => m.MarketAllocations.get_Item(value(ASP._Page_Views_AdProfile_Edit_cshtml+<>c__DisplayClass2).i).Provider1Id
```

When I use the provider1Id property off of the view model the expression is this:

```
m => m.Provider1Id
```

I have a work around (a helper function in the view model that takes the id and provides a select list with the correct value selected) but it's messy and involves bodging a repository into the view model so it's not ideal.

Does anyone know how to make DropDownListFor work correctly with arrays of objects like this?

Edit:  Sorry, should have mentioned this is MVC 4, hosted in IIS 8.5.

Comment: Where you create `selectlist`, you have to pass default selected value in `SelectList` constructor

Comment: If that was the case it wouldn't work for the Provider1Id property that is on the EditViewModel, which it does.  I also use this helper in a number of other views and it defaults correctly on all of them. It's only when the property is in an array of objects that it fails.

Comment: Unfortunately `DropDownListFor()` does not work as expected in a `for` loop. You either need use a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `MarketAllocation` and pass the `SelectList` as additional ViewData ([refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507948/dropdownlist-how-select-default-value/28510421#28510421)) or you need to generate a new `SelectList` in each iteration and set the `selectedValue` property