# asp.net MVC set default value for dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm displaying a dropdown list for countries, which is populated from a database call in the controller. On page load I would like the selected value to default to 'United States'. How do I do this?

Code from view:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new SelectList(Model.CountriesDDL, "CountryCode", "Country"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DropDownList how select default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507948/dropdownlist-how-select-default-value)

Comment: You have a few ways of going about this. You can always create the list in the controller and select a default item there. You can either put the list of SelectedListItems in your model or in a ViewBag. You can always use Jquery, and when the Window loads select an item based on your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

In your GET action, you can set the value of `Country` property to the CountryCode of United states (*or whatever country you want to set as default*) of your view model

```
public ActionResult Show()
{
  var vm = new YourViewModel();
  vm.CountriesDDL = GetCountriesFromSomeWhere();
  vm.Country="United States";
  return View(vm);
}
```

Assuming `Country` is of type string

Comment: Let's say the dropdown list is on a form submission page. What happens if a user were to select "Canada" from the drop down list and submit the form, but the form is invalid. Would the dropdown list still show "Canada" or would it default back to "United States"?

Comment: When you change to Canada, the Country will be updated to Canada in the HttpPost when it receives the form data.